# Parcel typescript module augmentation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parceljs

I'm trying to ship a lib that uses [typescript module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) with Parceljs but it doesn't seem to bundle those module augmentations. I'm not able to use the properties in the project that import the lib generated with Parcel.

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "dist/module.js",
  "types": "dist/types.d.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "latest"
  }
}
```

Example that I try to ship with Parcel and Typescript augmentation.

```
import { Components, createTheme, PaletteOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface Palette {
    ternary: Palette['primary'];
    quaternary: Palette['primary'];
    gridColor: string;
    logoColor: string;
  }
  interface PaletteOptions {
    ternary?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    quaternary?: PaletteOptions['primary'];
    gridColor?: string;
    logoColor?: string;
  }
}

export const defaultTheme = createTheme();
```

My exported defaultTheme that comes from the lib built with Parcel won't be shipped with additional properties that I defined here. I would like them to be available.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified reproduction of the library package and how you're consuming it? Two thoughts in the meantime: (1) the example in the typescript docs that shows how module augmentation works seems to show that the consumer of the augmentation would import from two _separate_ files, which runs against the idea of bundling your library code into a single file (e.g. the whole point of parcel). (2) your package.json is missing a `types` field - without it parcel won't generate any `.d.ts` files at all - see [docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/typescript/#generating-typings)

Comment: I edited my question, types field was defined I just forgot it in my initial message

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is [a bug in parcel](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7306).

**Update (2021-11)**: This [PR to fix this bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/7315) was accepted. The fix is available in `version 2.0.0-nightly.296` and later ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@parcel/transformer-typescript-types/v/2.0.0-nightly.926)), and should also ship in the next release of `@parcel/transformer-typescript-types` after `2.0.1`. If you're using version `2.0.1` or earlier, read on for a workaround.

You can work around the issue by using `tsc` to generate the `.d.ts` files for your project. Here's how you would do that:

1. Make sure your `package.json` is configured to tell parcel to output files with the same name as the root source file (e.g. if the root source file is `/src/index.ts`, make sure that you have `"main": "dist/index.js"` in your `package.json`)
2. Add a `tsconfig.json` with the following contents:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "rootDir": "./src",
       "declaration": true,
       "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
       "outFile": "./dist/index.js",
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add a command to your build step that deletes the `.d.ts` file generated by parcel, and creates a new one with `tsc`. E.g. `parcel build` becomes `parcel build && rimraf dist/index.d.ts && tsc`

I know this isn't pretty, but hopefully it will unblock you.

Here's [a repo where you can see an example of both the bug and the workaround](https://github.com/astegmaier/stackoverflow-ts-module-augmentation).

Comment: My [PR to fix this issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/7315) was accepted. The fix is available in the nightly channel - version 2.0.0-nightly.296 and later. It should be available in stable channel in the next release after 2.0.1.

Comment: The bug is back in 2.6.2.